# Pandas stacked bar plot

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have the following bar plot in pandas. However, I want the orange bar to be inside of the blue bar (one bar for each index on the x-axis), without changing the "max" bar value (the max has to be at 2540 for all the indices). Does anyone have any suggestions?

```
totalproteins= [2540, 2540, 2540, 2540, 2540, 2540, 2540, 2540]
actualproteins= [949, 945, 589, 345, 299, 237,  165, 165 ]
index = ["IHD", "CM", "ARR", "VD", "CHD", "CCD", "VOO", "OTH"]
df = pd.DataFrame({'totalproteins': totalproteins,'actualproteins': actualproteins}, index=index)
df.plot.bar(rot=0)
```

[image]

Comment: `df['totalproteins'] = df['totalproteins'] - df['actualproteins'];df.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)`How about this?